# How to create hibernate-friendly MySQL database fields with JPA 2 and HBN maven plugin?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

Is there any way I can use JPA or hibernate annotations to specify the exact type and length (according to MySQL) the field should be in the database?

For example:

```
@Entity
@Table { appliesTo="test" }
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private string info;

    public void setInfo(String i) {
       info = i;
    }

    @Column { name="id", length="25" }
    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }
}
```

I would like to reverse-engineer this class using the hibernate-maven-plugin and I would like to add "varchar 35" or something to the @Column annotation so that when I do the reverse engineering the fields are created as I specify and with lengths I specify.

Also, what is the difference between using the "Column" annotation on a java field (eg private long age) vs a getter method (Where I normally see it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Attribute [columnDefinition](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition%28%29) in Column annotation is there for such a needs. If such a detailed control over generated SQL DDL is not needed - length, precision, and scale attributes can be useful.

You should not spread persistence annotations to both fields and methods. As long as they are consistently placed, it will be fine. Persistence provided (like Hibernate) chooses does it use fields or methods to persist values based to where annotations are located. If they in both, result is undefined and unlikely to work.

Comment: What is the difference between specifying length in the @column annotation, vs providing the length in the columnDefinition variable within that same annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example

```
@Column(name = "delFlag", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
private boolean delFlag;   

@Column(length = 30)
private String propertyState;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is concept of access mode for fields in entity.If you want to use mixed access mode (i.e. use annotations on fields for some properties and on getters for others) you can do it too.

For example :

Set the default access mode for the entity .

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Test implements Serializable {..}
```

This will default expects annotations at field level.
Then for the properties that you want to annotate on the getters, explicitly set the access type to PROPERTY:

```
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Column(length=25)
public String getInfo() { return info; }
```